# SQL Server - linked Oracle server: EXECUTE permission denied on 'xp_prop_oledb_provider'

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

Inside of our SQL Server, we have created a linked server to an Oracle server.  We ave mapped several users to the Oracle server and specified the credentials.  On the Linked Server 'Security' properties, it says, "For a login not defined in the list above, connections will:" and we have selected "Be made using this security context:" and specified an Oracle user with read-only access.

Now, when we open SQL Server Management Studio as a user that is not explicitly specified in the list defined for the Oracle linked server, it uses the credentials with read-only access to connect.  However, when we try to expand 'Catalogs' under the linked Oracle server, we receive the error:

```
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_prop_oledb_provider'
```

Answer (score 1):

On the SQL Server where the linked server is defined, execute:

```
Use MASTER
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.XP_PROP_OLEDB_PROVIDER TO public
```

Does anyone have any comments on the security implications of this?